# Вызов функции находящейся в другой функции и как изменить стиль элемента при наведении на другой

Tags: javascript

добрый день, есть код:

```
var c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6 = null;
var ch1 = 0;
var ch2 = ch1+1;
var ch3 = ch2+1;
var ch4 = ch3+1;
var ch5 = ch4+1;
var ch6 = ch5+1;
var cn =[ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,ch5,ch6], cr = [null];
var ch_id =[null], notice_id=[null];
function read_ch(callback) {

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', '../json/channels', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {

            callback(xobj.responseText);

        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);
}

read_ch(function(response_ch) {
    var chnl = JSON.parse(response_ch);
    show_chnl();


    function show_chnl(){
        for (var n = 0; n<6; n++){ 
            var ch = document.createElement('div'), notice = document.createElement('div');
            var elem =ch.style;
            var name = document.getElementById("cn_name"), notice_div = document.getElementById("notice");
            name.appendChild(ch).id="channelname"+n;
            ch.innerHTML=chnl.collection[cn[n]].er_lcn + " " +chnl.collection[cn[n]].title;
            elem.color= "white"; 
            elem.backgroundColor= "#525151"; 
            elem.fontSize= "24px"; 
            elem.padding= "20px"; 
            elem.display= "block"; 
            elem.width= "290px"; 
            elem.border="5px solid black";
            notice_div.appendChild(notice).id="notice"+n;
            notice.innerHTML = chnl.collection[cn[n]].description;
            notice.style.display = "none";
            ch.onfocus = function(){
            notice.style.display = "block";
        };



    }

    for (n = 0; n<6; n++){cr[n]=chnl.collection[cn[n]].epg_channel_id}
    return cr;
}});

function read_pr(callback) {

    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', '../json/programms', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {

            callback(xobj.responseText);

        }
    };
    xobj.send(null);

}

read_pr(function(response_pr) {
    var progs = JSON.parse(response_pr);
    var chan1 = [];
    var chnum = [];
    var chan = [];
    var j =0;
    var k = 0;
    var str = ["str_1","str_2","str_3","str_4","str_5","str_6"];
    for(var i = 0; i<6; i++){
        for(k = 0; k<progs.collection.length; k++){
            if(progs.collection[k].channel_id == cr[i]) {chan[j]=progs.collection[k]; j=j+1} 
        }
    }
    function cr_div(){
        var ndiv = document.createElement('div');
        var name = document.getElementById(str[j]);
        var elem = ndiv.style;
        name.appendChild(ndiv).id="channel"+i;
        ndiv.innerHTML=chan[i].title;
        elem.width=chan[i].duration/5+"px";
        elem.color="white";
        elem.backgroundColor= "#525151";
        elem.padding="20px";
        elem.border="5px solid black";
        elem.display="inline-block";

    }
    console.log("ид",cr,"массив",chan);
    for(i = 0; i<chan.length; i++){
        switch(chan[i].channel_id){
            case cr[0]:{
                j=0;
                cr_div();
                break;
            }
            case cr[1]:{
                j=1;
                cr_div();
                break;
            }
            case cr[2]:{
                j=2;
                cr_div();
                break;
            }
            case cr[3]:{
                j=3;
                cr_div();
                break;
            }
            case cr[4]:{
                j=4;
                cr_div();
                break;
            }
            case cr[5]:{
                j=5;
                cr_div();
                break;
            }
            case cr[6]:{
                j=6;
                cr_div();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
});

function move_ch(){
    var up_button = document.getElementById("channelmove");
    up_button.onClick = function move_up(){
        ch1=ch1+1;
        show_chnl();
    };
}
```

Как из последней функции можно сделать обращение к функции show_chnl?
Так же упорно не хочет работать фокус, помимо него пытался задать стиль ховер, загружая данные в head. не было никакой реакции, у меня создаются блоки notice, которые должны появляться только при наведении на channelname. Использовать необходимо только нативный js.

Comment: *Как из последней функции можно сделать обращение к функции show_chnl?* - никак, потому что эта функция объявлена внутри другой функции. Делай ее глобальной и тогда можно будет

Comment: я понимаю, что ее можно сделать глобальной, но тут парсится json файл, получается так, что в нее еще нужно передать данные.

Comment: ну так и передай ей эти данные

Answer (score 0):

В глобальной области 
(там где объявлены var ch2 = ch1+1; var ch3 = ch2+1; var ch4 = ch3+1; var ch5 = ch4+1; var ch6 = ch5+1;) объяви переменную. В функции read_ch этой переменной присвой свою функцию и вызови её из нужной тебе функции